# Return 1 if any bits in an integer equal 1 using bit operations in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I've been thinking about this problem for hours.  Here it is:

> Write an expression that returns 1 if a given integer "x" has any bits equal to 1. return 0 otherwise.

I understand that I'm essentially just trying to figure out if x == 0 because that is the only int that has no 1 bits, but I can't figure out a solution. You may not use traditional control structures. You may use bitwise operators, addition, subtraction, and bit shifts. Suggestions?

Comment: Is this for any size integer, or do you have a known size?

Comment: Addition and subtraction are not bitwise operations...

Comment: If one of the answers solves your problem, you should check it as "accepted".

Answer (score 5):

Here's the best I could come up with:

```
y = (((-x) | x) >> (BITS - 1)) & 1;
```

where BITS = 32 for 32 bit ints, i.e. `BITS = sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT;`

Here's a test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int BITS = sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT;

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        int x = atoi(argv[1]);
        int y = (((-x) | x) >> (BITS - 1)) & 1;

        printf("%d -> %d\n", x, y);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wait, (-x)|x isn't always 1??

Comment: For 0 is 0 else MSB bit equals 1

Comment: `-x >> (BITS - 1)` works fine I think. The `| x` is unnecessary because you will be shifting those bits anyway

Comment: -x does not work on negative numbers. -x | x sets 1 MSB bit, since one of both values is negative.

Comment: @Marlon: as @ralu says, you need to make sure that if x is negative you still get the MSB set, hence the need for `-x | x`

Comment: Hello @PaulR !! I am looking at a similar problem... I am writting a command and I want to check if x=0. The only conditional command is JMP N, which checks if the currect value is negative, if yes, then we go to the command N, if no, we just continue. So, we have to check is x<0. But we also have to check if x>0, but how? Using the bitwise operation NOT it is not the negative of the number, it is the bitwise inverse....

Comment: @MaryStar: you can just do it with two tests: do a JMP N to handle negative values, then do a bitwise NOT and do a second JMP N - this second test will handle positive values which are > 0, however a zero value will still be zero after a bitwise NOT.

Comment: But by the bitwise NOT a do we get the negative number of a? @PaulR

Comment: @MaryStar: the bitwise NOT gives you the 1's complement, but that doesn't matter - all that matters is that the sign bit will get set if x is positive, so you can just use JMP N to test this.

Answer (score 5):

Using !!x will give you the right answer. Since !0 = 1 and !(any nonzero number) = 0.

Comment: From C perspective that is the best solution, but it is not respecting the constraints of the task.

Answer (score 1):

For a 32-bit value, the following will work for all bit-patterns.

```
return (a | -a) >> 31;
```

Comment: ensure shift is logical and NOT arithmetical of course - in C use unsigned type.

Comment: Also note that the solution "return ~(x ^ x-1) >> 31;" above, does not work for value 0x80000000.

Comment: for arithmetic shift it can be modified to `-((a | -a) >> 31)`

Answer (score 0):

Mask each of the bits individually, shift them all down to the lsb position, and or them together.

Comment: as in 16 different expressions for 16 bits? I think there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could just cast your `int` to a `bool`.  But I doubt that's the purpose of your homework ;-)

Comment: `bool` does not exist in standard C (only C99).

Comment: True, and it likely uses branch logic internally, which violates the rules of the homework.  But in the general case (if supported by the language) it is a concise way to get the job done.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: I think I'd call C99 "standard C" and everything else "out of date old C".

Answer (score 0):

For 32 bit integers

```
int return_not_zero(int v)
{
  r=v;
  r=(r&0xFFFF) | (r>>16); 
  r=(r&0xFF) | (r>>8);
  r=(r&0x0F) | (r>>4);
  r=(r&0x03) | (r>>2); 
  r=(r&0x01) | (r>>1); 
  return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

0 || number - this will return 0 only if the number is 0 and will return 1 if the number is any other number than 0. Since a number without any bit as 1 will be equal to 0, we need to check it with 0.

Comment: `||` is not allowed because it's a logical operator

Answer (score -1):

untested, that's the first thing that came to my mind:

```
 while(n & pow(2, e) == 0 && e++ <= 16) ;  // 16 or 32
```

if `e == 16` after the loop n is 0.

Comment: You seem to be using a lot more than just bitwise operations here ?

Comment: `pow(2, e)` should be changed to `1 << e` which is much faster and also satisfies the requirements

Answer (score -1):

```
int any_bits_to_one(unsigned int n) {
  int result = 0, i;

  for (i=0; !result && i < sizeof(unsigned int) * 8; i++)
    result |= (n & (1<<i)) ? 1 : 0;

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Bitwise AND with 0 and any number must equal zero, but the only foolproof test would be with 0xFFFF, or every bit being set. To get all bits set, you should have a signed int, and assign it -1. You will then have an int with all bits set to 1, regardless of size.

So my answer would be to bitwise AND it with -1

Answer (score -1):

How about !(x&&~x)&&x ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
  int x;
  scanf("%d",&x);
  printf("%d\n",(!(x&&~x)&&x));
}
```

It seems work, but I'm not sure when overflow happens.

Comment: If you are allowed `&&` then `x && 1` is a bit simpler

Answer (score -2):

I believe this is the simplest way.

```
return !!(0|x);
```

The only time your x will not have a 1 in it is when all bits are 0, or x == 0. So 0|0 -> 0  else 0|x -> non zero.

Comment: unfortunately `!` is a logical operator which is not allowed

Answer (score -2):

In C language, any value other than ZERO (either positive or negative) is treated as TRUE. And there should be a condition to check either your question's solution returns a ZERO or ONE (or other than ZERO). Therefore this answer is perfectly as per your requirement. This uses only bit-wise operators.

```
return (x & 0xFFFF);
```

This line returns ZERO when neither of any bit in "x" is 1, and returns Non-Zero (TRUE in a sense) when any of the bit is 1 in "x".